# Archive Large files to DVD - span?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

I have about 16GB of data that I'd like to burn onto DVDs. Many small files and a few large (one is 13GB).

I'm looking for a good option to get all that data spanned across a few DVDs. I realize one option could be to use 7zip to make multiple archives, each 4.7GB, but before I go that route I figured I'd ask here first. :-)

I tried the built-in backup app that comes with Windows 7, but it didn't seem to want to span DVD and crapped out when the first DVD filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You best option is really the split archives using 7zip. It's simple, easy, and will use up every last bit of each DVD (excluding overburning). This way you'll also gain a extra space if the content isn't already compressed.

On that note, if the content *is* already compressed you might want to turn off compression or use lower compression settings to save some CPU time since you won't gain much space from compressing compressed content.

I recently backed up 1.36 TB of media to many DVDs using 7zip.

Comment: *sigh* yeah... I had already started the 7zip compress/split. :-)
Just thinking that *surely* there's utilities already out there capable of spanning DVDs.

Comment: Oh fer pete's sake. I had 7zip split do DVD sized (preset option) and the resulting files appear to be just a little too large to burn to disk...

Comment: For posterity's sake: Using the 7zip split files worked just fine with Win7's built-in "Copy to DVD" function.